# How to enable horizontal scroll in vue-tables-2(ClientTable)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to use vue-tables-2(ClientTable) component in my Vue.js project.
What I was expect is it made horizontal scrollbar appear automatically when number of columns increased.

I tried several css settings or options of ClientTable, but it did not work.
Should I create css or options ?  Or Should I find another way to solve it ?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

My basic code was as follows.(There are 10 columns but ClientTable did not
make appear horizontal scroll bar)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12"></script>
<script src="./vue-tables-2.min.js"></script>

<body>
<h3 class="vue-title">Simple</h3>

<div id="app">
  <v-client-table :columns="columns" :data="data" :options="options">
    <a slot="email" slot-scope="props" :href="`mailto:${props.row.email}`">
    {{props.row.email}}
    </a>
  </v-client-table>
</div>
</body>


<script>
console.assert(typeof Vue !== 'undefined');
Vue.use(VueTables.ClientTable);

var vue = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    columns: [
      'id',
      'name',
      'email',
      'email',
      'email',
      'email',
      'email',
      'email',
      'email'
    ],
    data: getData(),
    options: {
      headings: {
        id: 'id',
        name: 'Name',
        email: 'Mail Address'
      },
      sortable: [
        'id', 'name'
      ],
      texts: {
        filterPlaceholder: 'Search'
      }
    }
  }
});

function getData() {
  return [{
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'sample1',
      'email': 'sample1@example.com',
      'group_name': 'Human Resource'
    },
    {
      'id': 2,
      'name': 'sample2',
      'email': 'sample2@example.com',
      'group_name': 'Human Resource'
    },

    {
      'id': 3,
      'name': 'sample3',
      'email': 'sample3@example.com',
      'group_name': 'Accounting'
    },
    {
      'id': 4,
      'name': 'sample4',
      'email': 'sample4@example.com',
      'group_name': 'General'
    }
  ];
}
</script>
```